# How do I get ssize_t to output bytes copied?

Tags: c

When trying to use ssize_t to print out the number of bytes copied from file 1 to file2 I can't seem to get the output to show on my terminal.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   int fp, fq;
   int size = 0;
   ssize_t bytesRead, bytesWritten;

   char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

   mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH; 

   fp = open(argv [1], O_RDONLY);
   if (fp == -1) {
     perror("The source file cannot be opened in read mode");
     return 1;
   }
   fq = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_EXCL | O_CREAT, mode);
   if (fq == -1) {
     perror("File could not be opened in write mode");
     return 2;
   }

   while((bytesRead = read (fp, &buffer, BUF_SIZE))>0){
     bytesWritten = write (fq, &buffer, (ssize_t)bytesRead);
   }
   size = ftell(fp);
   printf("Contents of size %zd copied\n", bytesRead);
   close (fp);
   close(fq);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%zd"` is not the specified printf specifier for `ssize_t` - it has none.  Suggest cast to a wide type like `printf("%lld\n", (long long) bytesRead);`.

Comment: What if the point of code `size = ftell(fp);`?  `size` not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample `bytesRead` contains the number of bytes read in the last call to `read` and each iteration of the `while` loop overwrites the existing value.

Add another variable `totalBytesRead`, initialize it to 0, and perform `totalBytesRead += bytesRead;` inside the loop. Then `totalBytesRead` will hold the total number of bytes read.

That being said, you are not checking any errors from `write`, thus the variable will contain the bytes read not written (currently for example your code will continue reading even if writing fails. You can add another variable `totalBytesWritten` as well, perform the same logic as for `totalBytesRead` in each iteration and compare if you wrote everything you read.

Comment: It was hard to understand from your question if you get an incorrect value or no output at all - that being said the error described in the answer will still provide you an incorrect value.